# Can I use docker to run a full linux install on osx?

Tags: linux, macos, docker

I know I can run headless linux with docker but is it possible to run a full desktop version of linux with it?

I have a macbook air and the stock options of dual booting or running a vm take too much memory and disk space, docker seems to be lighter so it would be convenient if it can do this

Answer (score 2):

You can install a VNC server in the container. How well it works with Gnome or other DE and on macOS, I can't tell, but a quick Google shows that there are some images with [Gnome+VNC combo](https://hub.docker.com/r/garland/dockerfile-ubuntu-gnome/) so it might be feasible.

There are some limitations, though. To run a Linux container on macOS, there has to be running a Linux VM somewhere, because Docker only isolates the processes in a container, but the kernel used is still that of the host machine.

These days, when you download Docker from the official site, it brings a small VM with it that acts transparently for you. But the VM still needs some RAM and the Kernel the VM is running can be missing something you need.

Depending on what you want to use it for, it may be enough, or you might be better off with a full VM.

Also, consider "Linux-like" repositories that contain a lot of applications ported directly for macOS, like **Homebrew** or **Macports** if you only want some tools (e.g. GNU versions of grep, awk, etc...), but don't really care what OS they run on.

*I tried both of them. My personal preference is for Homebrew that I would call more active and slightly easier to use.*